# my background image is overlapping my navbar?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-position, z-index

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0%;
  margin: 0%;
}
#navigation{
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 7rem;
  box-shadow:  0 4px 14px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.829), 0 6px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
.logo{
  flex:0.7;
  width: 3rem;
  z-index: 2;
}
#nav-links{
  flex: 2;
  z-index: 2;
}
#nav-links ul{
  display: flex;
  z-index: 2;
}
#nav-links ul li{
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  padding: 0rem 1rem;
}
#nav-links ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0rem 2.5rem;
  color: rgb(6, 177, 20);
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
}
#btns{
  flex: 0.7;
}
#cirlce{
 
  height: 49rem;
  width: 100%; 
 margin-top: 0px;
 top: 7rem;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;

 
  clip-path: circle(62.2% at 50% 0%); 
  background-color: black;
  background-image: url(./shrishti-flowers-2.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 50rem;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Alegreya+Sans:wght@400;500&family=Ballet&family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="terms.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/dcd878f67c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab:wght@500&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

  </head>
  <body>
   <header>
     <div id="navigation">
       <div class="logo">
           <img src="./SHRISHTI FLOWERS - Copy.png" alt="" style="height: 7rem; width: 7rem;">
           
       </div>
       <div id="nav-links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
          </ul>
       </div>
       <div id="btns">
          <button id="complaint" class="btns">complaint</button>
          <button id="contact" class="btns">Contact us</button>
       </div>
     </div>
    
   </header>
    <div id="cirlce"></div>
  </body>
</html
```

Hello guys I am stuck in a problem , I don,t know  how do I send  this semi circle to ,I am new to CSS and don't know much about z index  . (The image is not visible so I have used and black background instead). I will be glad if you guys can fix this . ( sry for my bad english )   ................................

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `background-color` to the navbar!